# How to avoid creation of a view if it is already exist

Tags: wpf, mvvm, object-lifetime

I have a listbox which looks like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Clients}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <controls:ClientItem />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

There are several tabs in my window and the Clients collection is constructed depending on a selected tab. The problem is that the ClientItem constructor is called every time I switch the tabs, and the gui works slowly. There are normally 10-20 clients in the listbox and I can see in the vs profiler that a ClientItem constructor consumes the most part of time.

Is it possible to tell wpf not to create ClientItem view if it already exists?

Comment: `There are several tabs` - your tabs in TabControl?

Comment: No, they aren't. I have a complicated window which has several states and depending on this state I show a certain view. So, the problem comes when I change the state.

Comment: post your full code and XAML.